# Returning reference to a function template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class called `Managed` which has a static templated `create()` function. I'm trying to write a helper which returns that function when passed the Managed subclass type.

```
typedef std::function<ScreenBase::ptr (WindowBase&)> ScreenFactory;

template<typename T>
ScreenFactory screen_factory() {
    ScreenFactory ret = &T::create<WindowBase&>;
    return ret;
}
```

Because create itself takes template arguments, I explicitly try to get a reference to the instantiation that takes a WindowBase&. As far as I can see the above code should work.

However, when I try to call it, I get the following error:

```
error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
ScreenFactory ret = &T::create<WindowBase&>;
                               ~~~~~~~~~~^
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any pointers?

Comment: `&T::template create<WindowBase&>`

Comment: @PiotrS. Perfect thanks! If you post that as answer I'll mark it correct :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `template` keyword:

```
template<typename T>
ScreenFactory screen_factory() {
    ScreenFactory ret = &T::template create<WindowBase&>;
    //                      ~~~~~~~^
    return ret;
}
```

For details please refer to [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/3953764)